# Add slight space between between table and page numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have applied the responsive style to my jQuery Datatable using this [link](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).
As shown in the link, there is a slight space or a new line between the table and the page number at the bottom right of the table. I have achieved the same in my table as well.
But, as per my requirement I have set a vertical height of my table using the jQuery datatable options as shown below.

```
"scrollY": "250px",
"scrollCollapse": true,
```

After applying this change the vertical size is set, scroll bar is fine but there is no space or little space between the table and the page numbers as shown in the below image.

[image]

How to add space or make it look exactly like before applying the Scroll-vertical.

Comment: Why is this so tough? You can use CSS right?

Comment: Lemme know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```css
.dataTables_paginate {margin-top: 15px;}
```

Adjust the `15px` to whatever you want. Also, if you have many datatables inside your body, it is wise to encapsulate a particular one inside an `id` and give the CSS this way:

```css
#myDataTable .dataTables_paginate {margin-top: 15px;}
```

Comment: Overridden the .dataTables_paginate and this code has worked for me.
    div.dataTables_paginate {
      margin-top: 10px !important;
    }

Comment: Great... Usage of `!important` is not advisable. @srk

Comment: Yes. What is the alternative for !important?